# Generic Mediatr Handler not found

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

I'm trying to register a generic request handler for a generic request, but I'm getting the error below when calling

```cs
await _mediator.Send(new ExchangeOrderRequest<ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent>());
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not found for request of
> type
> MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[MyNamespace.ExchangeOrderRequest`1[MyNamespace.ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent],MediatR.Unit]`.
> Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
> for examples.

As side note, for giggles, I was able to inject an instance of `IRequestHandler<ExchangeOrderRequest<ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent>>` into a controller just fine.

```cs
// Some assembly scanning, doesn't find my handler
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup), typeof(ExchangeOrderRequest), typeof(IDocumentMessage), typeof(OrderExecution.Handler));

// Try to manually add the handler.  Still doesn't find it
services.AddTransient<IRequestHandler<ExchangeOrderRequest<ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent>>, ExchargeOrderRequestHandler<ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent, ExchangeOrderRequest<ExchangeOrderResponseSuccessEvent>>>();




public class ExchargeOrderRequestHandler<TEvent, TRequest> : IRequestHandler<TRequest> 
    where TRequest : ExchangeOrderRequest<TEvent> 
    where TEvent : ExchangeOrderEvent
{
     // Stuff
}`

public class ExchangeOrderRequest<T>: DocumentMessage, IRequest where T: ExchangeOrderEvent
{
     // Stuff
}

public class ExchangeOrderEvent : IEvent
{
      // Stuff
 
        
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue...

However, I am able to register the handler like this..

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(CustomHandler<,>));
```

This works for only one generic handler... I have many... I need to be able to do something like this:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(CustomHandler1<,>));
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(CustomHandler2<,>));
//etc...
```

When I try and do this... no matter what command I send to MediatR it resolves the last handler I registered.. So naturally the type constraints are violoated and a runtime exception occurs.